# Xcode doesn't recognize key binding

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, xcode4.4

I use Xcode with the key bindings heavily overriden to match my taste, for example, I use `Alt+[`/`]` as shortcuts for the "Jump to previous/next placeholder" commands. Unfortunately, with the latest 4.4.1 update these bindings stopped working and now I'm getting quote characters (`“‘`) dumped into the text editor instead. The binding setup is still marked as valid (no conflicts are reported by Xcode). Any thoughts on this?

OSX 10.7.4, Xcode 4.4.1 (4F1003), standard US layout, alu keyboard if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out there are multiple entries for the seemingly same function, as shown in the image below:

[image: Bindings]

Setting both to the same binding did the trick.